# Install Arabic language on Android ICS

Tags: languages

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 running Android ICS. How can I install the Arabic language on my phone keyboard as it is not listed?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**

Download and install [Language Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wanam).

> ' Need Root ACCESS '

**Step 2 :**

and, add `Arabic language` for Menu.
Then go to `Language and Input` from `Settings`.
Tap "`Configure Input Methods.`"

**Step 3 :**

Uncheck the "Use System Language" check box. This unlocks the other active input methods for use.

Select the check boxes for the `keyboards and/or voice input` methods you wish to add. This adds them for use during text input, as long as you use the standard Android keyboard.

**Step 4 :**

then add Arabic Language, and enjoy.